# Appointment from ExchangeService: how to access associated contacts?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, contacts, exchangewebservices, appointment

It's about Outlook 2003, Exchange 2010 (SP2) and the EWS managed API in C#.
I'm trying to get all appointments from the Exchangeserver, this works fine:

```
ExchangeService service = exchangeService.Service;
CalendarFolder calendarfolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
ItemView view = new ItemView(calendarfolder.TotalCount);
if (calendarfolder.TotalCount > 0)
{
    FindItemsResults<Item> calendarItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, view);
    foreach (Item item in calendarItems)
    {
        if (item is Appointment)
        {
            //...do something
        }
    }
}
```

The first line returns an ExchangeService with all required preferences.

The only problem is this one: I can't get the associated contacts of the appointment. I really need them - not the invited users, only the associated contacts. 
Every other attribute is available, except this one...

Please, anyone an idea? I'm working on this since months, and I suspect I already know almost every single article about the EWS managed API on Google without any success on this point.

Thanks in advance.